# Call a java Rest webservice on email event

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have a webservice x exposed.If I get a mail in my email containing attachment I want to call
this webservice.I am not asking for code.I am asking your suggestion in high level how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need REST. So - you cant use org.apache.http.client library. (Other way, if you'll have web service you can use `wsimport` to create WebService java-client.)
2. Use javax.mail library to open mailbox and iterate letters.
3. Process letters. Mark or delete processed letters.
4. Add crontab/sheduler task to run your app. (As for me, It's better, than create a thread app). Dont forget to use `run-one` option to prevent double execution.

Here some code example that reads "*.xls" files from mailbox messages:

```
    public void processEmail() throws MessagingException {

    Store emailStore = null;
    Folder emailFolder = null;

    try {
        // connecting
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

        Main.getLog().debug("CONNECT TO : " + config.mailServer + " ["
                + config.mailUser + "] DEBUG: "+config.debug);

        // check mailbox
        emailStore = emailSession.getStore("imaps");
        emailStore.connect(config.mailServer, config.mailUser,
                config.mailPassword);
        Main.getLog().debug("CONNECT DONE");

        emailFolder = emailStore.getFolder("INBOX");
        emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

        Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
        Main.getLog().debug("RECEIVED " + messages.length + " MESSAGSES");

        // for each letter
        for (Message message : messages) {
            try {
                Main.getLog().debug("\nPROCESS LETTER : "
                        + message.getSubject());
                if (message.getFlags().contains(Flags.Flag.DELETED)) {                      
                    continue; // don't process such letters
                }

                if (message.getFlags().contains(Flags.Flag.SEEN)) {
                    continue; // don't process such letters
                }
                // 
                Map<String, String> parseResult = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String auditId = "";

                // get file
                if (message.getContent() instanceof Multipart) {
                    Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
                    for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
                        BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
                        if (!Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(bodyPart
                                .getDisposition())) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        // Process file
                        if (bodyPart.getFileName().contains(".xls")) {
                            auditId = maintainExcelFile(bodyPart.getInputStream());
                        }
                    }
                } else if (message.getContent() instanceof BASE64DecoderStream) {
                    // Process file
                    if (message.getFileName().contains(".xls")) {
                        auditId = maintainExcelFile(((BASE64DecoderStream) message
                                .getContent()));
                    }
                }
                if (!config.debug && auditId!=null && !auditId.equals("")) { 
                    message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);
                } 
                if (!config.debug) {
                    sendAcceptMail(message, auditId);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Process errors
                if (!config.debug) {
                    message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);
                    sendErrorMail(message, e);
                }
                Main.getLog().error(e.getMessage(), e);
                throw new Exception(e);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Main.getLog().error(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        emailFolder.close(true);
        emailStore.close();
    }
}
```